# Increase the navigation arrow size in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm trying to create a a carousel with two left right navigation arrows in bootstrap 4.

Here is my code for controllers

```
<!-- Carousel controls -->
                        <a class="carousel-control left carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left text-dark"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control right carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right text-dark"></i>
                        </a>
```

So as you can see I have Used font awsome to insert the arrows. Now my issue is the default arrows are too small

How can I increase the size of two arrows?

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to increase the size of the arrows you can simply increase the font size, as you are using font awsome.

If you want to increase the font size of all the font awsome icons,

```
.fa{
 font-size: 100px;
}
```

But the above will increase the size of each an every Fa icons,

So instead of that to increase the sizes of only the arrows,

```
.fa-angle-left{
        font-size: 100px;
    }
    .fa-angle-right{
        font-size: 100px;
    }
```

So this will increase only the size of arrows.

Comment: Note this will change the size of all `fa-angle-left` icons. It's better to add a custom class, in case you use those arrows some place else.

Comment: To clarify my above comment, one of the great things with font awesome is the icons will default to the font size of the parent element. For example, if you add an icon in an `<h1>` tag, it will be big to go along with the header. If you add an icon in a `<small>` tag, it will be small to along with the small text. It's generally a bad idea to override this default behavior by hard coding specific icons to a set size.

Answer (score 0):

The wonderful thing about font awesome is you can apply CSS properties to them, changing things like color, size, etc. In this case, simply add a class to the icon and write a little CSS to change the size:

```html
<i class="nav-arrow fa fa-angle-left text-dark"></i>
```

```css
.nav-arrow {
    font-size: 1.5em; /* or whatever value you prefer */
}
```

If you don't want to add a custom class, you could also apply a size to the icons in the `carousel-control`:

```css
.carousel-control .fa-angle-left,
.carousel-control .fa-angle-right {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```